# SAML with EWS APIs

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365, adfs2.0

I have configured a ADFS server which has relying party trust configured to office 365. I am able to authenticate users in the O365 using ADFS server. Is it possible to use SAML token issued by this ADFS server and fetch calendar or mail details using EWS exchange APIs?

Comment: Crazy timing - I literally have the exact same question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you DirSynced ADFS and O365 (which uses Azure Active Directory)?

If so, did you have a look at the [Office 365 REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)?

[Code samples](http://dev.office.com/code-samples)

Just a thought!

Comment: Yes I already DirSynced ADFS and O365. I know about office 365 rest apis. My questions is how to utilise this setup of ADFS. I have a service which will call these rest apis. Users in my organisation will do a login to this service using a SAMl trust configuration bw my service and ADFS. I want to utilise the SAML certificate to finally call O365 REST Apis.

Comment: any changes on this?

Comment: There is a SAML flow that would cater for this - SAML Bearer Assertion Flow - but it's not implemented yet.